# addTextChangedListener inside a ListView is called every time while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, listener, getview

I have a ListView with an EditText (quantity box) on each row. When the user sets the desired quantity, the new value updates the corresponding column inside a SQLite database, than I repopulate the ListView with the modified values. 
To trigger this process I use the **addTextChangedListener** on the EditText which works just fine.

My Problem is that the listener is called each time while scrolling, and this triggers the above process, without even touching the quantity box.

How could I avoid the addTextChangedListener to be triggered while scrolling? Same problem happens with my **spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener**.  I have tried to get the listeners outside the getView method but without any luck...:(

the custom ListView:

```
public class PhotosListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItemsSetter> {

        DeleteImageListener dListener;
        private Context context;
        private int layoutResourceId;
        private ArrayList<ImageItemsSetter> data = new ArrayList<ImageItemsSetter>();   

        //standard constructor
        public PhotosListViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItemsSetter> data) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;            
        }           

        static class ViewHolder {

            public ImageView Img; 
            public EditText quantity;
            public Spinner spinner;
            public Button delete;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;
            ViewHolder holder = null;            

            ImageItemsSetter image = data.get(position);

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(); 

            holder.Img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Img);

            holder.quantity = (EditText) row.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            // holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(holder.quantity));           

            holder.spinner = (Spinner) row.findViewById(R.id.photo_format);
            holder.delete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteImage);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag(); 
        }           

         holder.Img.setImageBitmap(image.getTheImage());            
         holder.quantity.setText(image.getQuantity());


        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
                R.array.formats_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);       
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);     
        holder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //The delete button
        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           

                if (dListener != null) {  
                    dListener.onDeletePressed(position); 
                }       
            }           
            });      


        holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {     

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {                         
                dListener.onFormatChanged(parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), data.get(position).getName());              
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            }

        });

        holder.quantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

               @Override
               public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

               @Override    
               public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                 int count, int after) {  }

               @Override    
               public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                 int before, int count) {
                   dListener.onQuantityChanged(s.toString(), data.get(position).getName());
                }
              });


        return row;
        }


        /*
         private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

                private View view;              
                private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
                    this.view = view;
                }                           


                // 3. saving the quantity box before it gets outside the visible area
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { 
                     final EditText editText = (EditText) view; 
                     dListener.onQuantityChanged(editText.getText().toString(), "tom");

                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {


                }
            }
            */



        //Interface to send selected image's position for deletion
        public void setDeleteImageListener(DeleteImageListener listener) {  
            this.dListener = listener;  
        } 

        public static interface DeleteImageListener { 
            public void onDeletePressed(int position);
            public void onQuantityChanged(String quantity, String name);
            public void onFormatChanged(String format, String name);
        }
```

Host activity part (here I receive responses using 2 custom interfaces):

```
@Override
public void onQuantityChanged(String quantity, String name) {
    System.out.println("quantity set to: " + quantity + " " + name );
    datasource.updateImageQuantiry(name, quantity);
    rePopulateList(); 

}

@Override
public void onFormatChanged(String format, String name) {
    System.out.println("format set to: " + format + " name: " + name);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a scroll listener to your ListView, and set a flag somewhere to know if ListView is scrolling or not.
Then inside onTextChanged, check that flag before calling your listener.
This will work because the method AbsListView.OnScrollListener.onScrollStateChanged gets called before the scroll happens.

> public abstract void onScrollStateChanged (AbsListView view, int
>   scrollState)
>
> Callback method to be invoked while the list view
>   or grid view is being scrolled. If the view is being scrolled, this
>   method will be called before the next frame of the scroll is rendered.
>   In particular, it will be called before any calls to getView(int,
>   View, ViewGroup).

*You can even make your class PhotosListViewAdapter implement the OnScrollListener interface, and then set your adapter as the scroll listener for your ListView. That way you can manage the scrolling flag state inside your adapter.*

```java
public class PhotosListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener {

    public boolean scrolling;

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        scrolling = scrollState != SCROLL_STATE_IDLE ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    }

    //...
    //TextWatcher.onTextChanged()
    //if(!scrolling) dListener.onQuantityChanged(s.toString(), data.get(position));
    //...
}

//In your activity or fragment:
//myListView.setOnScrollListener(myPhotoListViewAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This could be an option. I have implemented OnScrollListener inside my PhotosListViewAdapter, but its methods are not being called. Why? I have tested inside the host activity, there it is working ok, but I need it inside the PhotosListViewAdapter to be able to set some flags (booldeans).

Comment: @EdmondTamas basically you need to make the edits as the snippet i added on the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have figured out now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your adapter is setting the text on the views as you scroll, which should kick off your listener.

Also, you should only set your listeners once, not everytime `getView()` is called.

Comment: How could I set the listeners once? Thanks.

Comment: I would have the `ViewHolder` be the listener, and in `getView()` I would set the data on the `ViewHolder` and have that "setData(data d)" method update the views.